# Easiest implement for a dynamically updating table on a webpage (java/css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I've googled this and researched it for a few days already; I'm trying to implement a dynamically updating table on a page of my website of projects I've completed. I've come across "DataTables Table plug-in for jQuery" which seems slick and uses CSS, and supports "DOM, Javascript, Ajax and server-side processing." I basically just want to install an Excel-like table on my page that is scrollable and doesn't require me to either re-publish that page every update or add lines of Java to a table file and upload the files to my host every time I have new content. I'm thinking of using Google Docs spreadsheet as I've had success with Google Calendar... but after weeks of fiddling with gcal-flow+jQuery to get that working and formatted/styled, I'm leary of tackling another such Google undertaking. Also, I have no knowledge of SQL whatsoever, and a soon-impending deadline :(  Also my per-month data will double and triple eventually, so the spreadsheet will be handling a lot of rows.

Is Google Docs the way to go here? Is it easier to code to a java doc and upload? Forgive my limited knowledge; it feels like I'm missing a very obvious solution to my dilemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide the details of your website, whether it is running on Apache or something else. Well assuming PHP can run over there, you could just use it to dynamically generate the table.

I'll give you a code snippet, which might help you, of course customize it as per your needs.

1. Create a PHP file, let us call it "dynamicTable.php". Whose content would be -

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- The following part is the css, modify it as per your needs -->
        <style>
            .table1 {
              color:blue;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- This part is the actual table, the data being generated dynamically by PHP -->
        
        <table class="table1">
        <?php
         /* Get contents from the data file */
         $tableContents = file_get_contents("tableData.txt");
         
         /* Split it out in rows */
         $tableContents = explode("\n",$tableContents);
         
         /* Generate the table based on the data */
         foreach($tableContents as $i=>$v)
         {
        ?>
         <tr>
        <?
          /* Splits the items in a row by TAB character, or more than 1 spaces */
          $row = preg_split('/\s+/', $v);
          
          foreach ($row as $item)
          {
           echo ($i==0 ? "<th>":"<td>").$item.($i==0 ? "</th>":"</td>");
          }
        ?>
         </tr>
        <?php
         }
        ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

2. Create a `tableData.txt` file in the same folder as of the dynamicTable.php file and put down your contents there, for example

```
    Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
    Mazda   BMW Audi    Honda   Hyundai
    RX7 GT3 A7  Accord  Santro
```

With the 1st line being the table column headers, and thereafter each line representing a row. Within each row, the data items are separated by a tab-space (tab-key).

In order to make the page dynamic, you just have to edit this text file in your server and edit / add the values you want. And it will automatically be reflected in your page, without having to re-publish the actual page.

3. On the contrary, you can go for a JQuery / Ajax, if you want to make the page really dyanamic (I figured out that is not your requirement). That will make the page auto-refresh when its open in the browser itself, when you update / edit a value in the data file.

Comment: Thanks @Chique this is incredibly helpful!